# How to delete animation's keyframes in blender?

Tags: rigging, keyframes

I'd like to remove all keyframes to make an animation pose, but it doesn't work at dopesheet and timeline. How could I solve this problem? [image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file (the armature only)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: sorry it's bigger than 24 mb. this is a linked file. is that reason I can't control keyframes?

Comment: Looks like it's an action ("biped_blenrigAction"). Have you tried to switch to the Action Editor and just create and assign a new one? Click the dropdown box ("Dope Sheet") and select "Action Editor". At the center of the Action Editor's header, there is a dropdown box with the current action "biped_blenrigAction". Click the X to remove it and then the "New" button to create your own action. Click the "shield" icon (Fake user) to protect it so it gets saved and not deleted when it's deselected (unused).

Comment: please only share the armature, not the mesh or other objects